# Why are there RAM chips with bus speed of 1600Mhz since there aren't CPUs that support more than 1333?

Tags: memory, cpu

It is not my profession but I think my question isn't that stupid :)

Intel i7-2600 supports RAM: DDR3 1066/1333 non ECC

Same for Xeon, Amd A4 & A6 and so forth..

Why are there RAM chips with bus speed of 1600Mhz?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Before memory controllers were integrated into the CPU, they actually operated at higher clock speeds.  The CPU integrated ones are still faster overall, due to not having a delay between memory controller and CPU, but for those discrete memory controllers (north bridge of chipset), you'd want the higher RAM.  It's somewhat ironic that you've tagged your question `fsb` and then mentioned the Core-i line and AMD APUs, none of which have a Front Side Bus.
2. The "supported" RAM speed of those CPUs is the **officially** supported speed.  Overclocking is quite common.
3. Even when the RAM chip is used at a lower frequency, the higher-spec RAM chips will have fewer wait states between e.g. address stable until first data word read back.  The clock speed controls the burst throughput within a RAM block.  There are many many other timing factors affecting system performance than burst throughput.

Comment: Good point about the [fsb] tag.  I didn't even see notice that.